# React native, select one item from flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a list of data in flatlist and I want that when user click on item it will select that only that item but it's selecting all item.  I don't know where did I mistake. Below is my code.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    isLoading: false,
    search: '',
    isClicked: false,
  });
  const {isLoading, search, isClicked} = state;

  <FlatList
        data={data}
        style={{marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(23)}}
        keyExtractor={(data) => data.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <>
            {!isClicked && item.id ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.container}
                onPress={() => setState({isClicked: true})}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: moderateScale(18),
                    height: moderateScaleVertical(18),
                    backgroundColor: colors.blackOpacity20,
                    borderRadius: moderateScale(18 / 2),
                  }}
                />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    ...commonStyles.fontSize15,
                    color: colors.themeColor,
                    marginLeft: moderateScale(18),
                  }}>
                  {item.tag}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.container}
                onPress={() => setState({isClicked: false})}>
                <Image
                  source={imagePath.checkboxActive}
                  style={{
                    width: moderateScale(18),
                    height: moderateScaleVertical(18),

                    borderRadius: moderateScale(18 / 2),
                  }}
                />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    ...commonStyles.fontSize15,
                    color: colors.themeColor,
                    marginLeft: moderateScale(18),
                  }}>
                  {item.tag}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      />
```

I don't what I did wrong here. can someone please help

Answer (score 1):

Your isClicked local state is common for all the elements of your list, meaning that if you trigger it all of them will have it as true.

The best way to solve this issue would be not to pass a boolean to isClicked but rather the item.id:

```
onPress={() => setState({isClicked: item.id})}>
```

and then

```
{isClicked !== item.id && item.id ? (
```

Also be careful, you are not maintenaing the state of search and isLoading with your way of updating the state, you should actually rather have:

```
onPress={() => setState({isLoading, search, isClicked: item.id})}>
```

If you need to handle multiple possible items clicked at the same time I'd recommend separating each item in their own component with their own isClicked state OR having an array of id for the isClicked values

Comment: not working, state is not changing to true for is clicked

Comment: State should not be true but the item.id

Comment: `  {
      id: 3,
      tag: 'Co Working',
    },` that's my data how id will make isClick true

Comment: If you need to handle multiple possible items clicked at the same time I'd recommend separating each item in their own component with their own isClicked state OR having an array of id for the isClicked values

Comment: so in  every item if I add  `isClicked: false` then how can I set it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a state variable `isClicked` to check if an item is selected, but since that state is the same for the entire component, once the `isClicked` is set to true, all items of the Flatlist will be re-rendered as selected because they will be checking the same variable. What you could do to achieve your goal is to put a isClicked flag individually inside each item, so only the item's flag is set to true once you click on it.

Something like:

```
<FlatList
    data={data}
    style={{marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(23)}}
    keyExtractor={(data) => data.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <>
        {item.isClicked && item.id ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.container}
            onPress={() => item.isClicked = true}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: moderateScale(18),
                height: moderateScaleVertical(18),
                backgroundColor: colors.blackOpacity20,
                borderRadius: moderateScale(18 / 2),
              }}
            />
            <Text
              style={{
                ...commonStyles.fontSize15,
                color: colors.themeColor,
                marginLeft: moderateScale(18),
              }}>
              {item.tag}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.container}
            onPress={() => item.isClicked = false}>
            <Image
              source={imagePath.checkboxActive}
              style={{
                width: moderateScale(18),
                height: moderateScaleVertical(18),

                borderRadius: moderateScale(18 / 2),
              }}
            />
            <Text
              style={{
                ...commonStyles.fontSize15,
                color: colors.themeColor,
                marginLeft: moderateScale(18),
              }}>
              {item.tag}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </>
    )}
  />
```

Comment: but it creates a problem that data will come from backend so the person who's working on backend will need to add that key to every item

Comment: and we can't do that `setState({item.isClick:true})` it will throw error

Comment: Not really, since the key doesn't exist inside the item object, it will be `undefined`, which has a boolean value equal to `false`, and then, on the click you set it to `true`, this key will only exist in the front-end, where it's needed.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to take out the setState part, I edited my answer to reflect what I'm trying to say

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code, it should give you an idea on how to make it work,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';



export default function App() 
{

   //API Data
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 0, title: "one" },
    { id: 1, title: "two" }
  ]);

  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState("");


  const list = <FlatList 
    data = {data}
    key = {key => key.id}
    renderItem = {({item}) => 
    {
      let styleObject = styles.normal

      if(item.id === clicked)
      {
        styleObject = styles.active
      }


      return <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => setClicked(item.id)}>
        <Text style = {styleObject}>{item.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    }}
  />


  return (
    <View>
     {list}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   active: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    margin: 20,
    padding: 20
  },
  normal: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    margin: 20,
    padding: 20
  }
});
```

Comment: same problem with that code selecting all item in list

Comment: i tried and it worked fine for me, post your latest code which you are trying

Comment: wait i will try it again

Comment: I have updated my code, try to copy paste the code and see if it works, and then do the necessary modifications based on your needs, works fine on my end

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/GXMgpHmnu => try with iOS device or android device. Not web